# Typoscript image size based on layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want to set the image height among other things based on the layout using typoscript. The setup I have works great for setting an image wrap etc but I can't get the height setting to work...

The documentation seems to suggest that what I have here should work:

```
temp.image < tt_content.image.20
tt_content.image.20 = CASE
tt_content.image.20 {
  key.field = layout
  default < temp.image
  1 < temp.image
  1 {
    1.file.width =
    1.file.height = 50m
  }
}
tt_content.textpic.20 = < tt_content.image.20.default
```

Anyone know what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `1.file.height = 50m` I instead needed to use:

```
equalH >
equalH = 50m
```